# Samsung Smart-TV SDK Internet Browser not available

Tags: html, samsung-smart-tv, television

I just recently downloaded and installed the Samsung Smart-TV SDK 4 (without the IDE, just the emulator). I'm doing this because I want to test the Web browser only, nothing else.

However, when I start up the emulator (2012 version), I can't find any apps when I get to smarthub. I've created a Samsung account but I see no default apps that would usually appear on the TV, not even the Internet browser.

Is there something I'm missing?! I just want to test the Internet Browser.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is provided for testing your own apps, not to run the apps that people who buy TVs/BRPs/etc get with their device.

Only apps you write and place in the `apps/` directory will appear.

That said, you can write an app that does nothing except:

```
location.href = "http://example.com/";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'll see if I can find a 'Hello World' app and try that. Cheers.

Comment: The IDE will generate a basic app for you. Just put the above code in the appropriate part of main.js.

Answer (score 1):

if i write an app with just location.href = "http://example.com/ is working (i have sdk 5.0) but the browser i get on the TV is not the same browser i get on the tv if i just lunch the integrated web browser app.
The big difference i see is that my app has a browser without the top bar with navigation controls and also there is no mouse pointer and i need to connect an external usb mouse to the tv

how should i do to implement this ?