# How to open system browser on samsung smart tv with javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, sdk, samsung-smart-tv

I am experimenting with Sammsung Smart TV Javascript SDK and wonder that I cannot open Links in System browser.

I have found this [Samsung Smart-TV SDK Internet Browser not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643059/samsung-smart-tv-sdk-internet-browser-not-available) which is not what I want because it is not possible to navigate in this window via TV remote control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung doesn't give web browser in their SDK because the actual application also cannot open the web browser, so there is no point to bring web browser to SDK.

Developing the TV Apps is little different with mobile apps, in the mobile we can bring our ordinary website and put them on webview or html viewer because the navigation for click and else is same with desktop browser. but in TV apps you should utilize the remote control as the main input.